# 'object is not callable' error while using selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium

I used the `browser.switch_to.alert().accept()` to handle a javascript alert popup.
But I got an error like this:

```
TypeError: 'Alert' object is not callable
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 19):

Alert object is not callable? Then you should stop calling it. So modify

```
browser.switch_to.alert().accept()
```

to

```
browser.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

(So remove the `()` after `alert`).