# How to use Selenium with python in Chrome to check for "Reload page?" alert and click Reload?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I have a bot that I'm testing and it works for the most part, but every once in a while when it navigates to a new page, Chrome throws a "Reload Page?" alert and it stops the bot. How can I add a check in the bot to look for this alert, and if it's there click the "Reload" button on the alert?

In my code I have

`options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")`

and

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path="chromedriver.exe")`

but it still happens every once in a while. Any advice?

Comment: Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003003/check-if-any-alert-exists-using-selenium-with-python) to check if there's an alert. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42005956/handle-alert-in-selenium-python) to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `driver.switch_to_alert` to handle this case.

I would also invoke `WebDriverWait` on the alert itself, to avoid the `NoSuchAlert` exception:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

def refresh_with_alert(driver):

    # wrap this in try / except so the whole code does not fail if alert is not present
    try: 
        # attempt to refresh
        driver.refresh()

        # wait until alert is present
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present())

        # switch to alert and accept it
        driver.switch_to.alert.accept()

    except TimeoutException:
        print("No alert was present.")
```

Now, you can call like this:

```
# refreshes the page and handles refresh alert if it appears
refresh_with_alert(driver)
```

The above code will wait up to 5 seconds to check if an alert is present -- this can be shortened based on your code needs. If the alert is not present, the `TimeoutException` will be hit in the `except` block. We simply print a statement that the alert does not exist, and the code will move on without failing.

If the alert **is** present, then the code will accept the alert to close it out.